# Android Dagger 2.11 with Kotlin, ContributesAndroidInjector Annotation issue

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm using `Dagger 2.11` with `Kotlin`. Everything is fine with `Dagger` but when i add `ContributesAndroidInjector` annotation to project i get this error:

```
e: 
...build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/devDebug/com/raqun/android/di/AppComponent.java:6: error: dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this interface because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
e: 

e: public abstract interface AppComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector<MyApp> {
e:
```

Here're the dependencies i use:

```
$rootProject.ext.daggerVersion = 2.11

compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$rootProject.ext.daggerVersion"
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$rootProject.ext.daggerVersion"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.ext.daggerVersion"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$rootProject.ext.daggerVersion"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.ext.daggerVersion"
```

I already added:

```
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

What i'm missing or doing wrong? 
Thanks for your help.

**Not:** I already tried cleaning gradle and re-building project.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is about my dependencies. Here're the working dependencies for `Dagger 2.11` and `Kotlin`.

```
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$rootProject.ext.daggerVersion"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.ext.daggerVersion"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$rootProject.ext.daggerVersion"
```

Thanks all for help.